# Display Particular Div on my another website

Tags: php, javascript

I two website abc.com content div with id 'abc' and another website def.com. content div with id 'def'. The Qns is how can I display content of div having id='abc' into div id='def'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to scrape content of abc.com, then search dom element to find div "abc", fetch its content and put it in def div of another site.
for scraping use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks Sabin for your effort... I will checking your link and report you ASAP.

Comment: @Ajay, go through the link, the code is well documented and its much easier than any other method.

Comment: @Ajay, I m glad that I helped you

Answer (score 1):

That can not be possible , reason is to read content you need to call some ajax request. And ajax never works between cross domain.

Comment: With a proper policy, AJAX works across domains - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing.

Comment: Ooooopppsssss Any Idea Pratik ?

Comment: for that you need to do something from server side only... and if content is not so difficult to display than suggestion to avoid it trying and repeating that on both sides. If possible make jQuery template of that part and load that in html.. that will reduce your work.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are trying to do is called `webpage scrapping`. You can not do it using client side Javascript alone as it gives cross-domain error. But you can use node.js - server side javascript.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/web-scraping-with-node-js/

Comment: Thanks CodefOrmer for your reply... Now I trying to solve my problem with your given solution..

Comment: Do not forget to accept the right answer which eventually helps you to get answers to your questions quickly from stackers.